# How can I test that a method is private using PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit

Using PHPUnit, I would like to test that a Class CANNOT be instantiated using the `__construct [ new Class(); ]` method as well as cannot be cloned, woken up etc.

Basically it is a Singleton class, and the `__construct`, `__clone` and `__wakeup` methods set to private to make sure it remains a Singleton.

But how can I test for that?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by catching the exception thrown by trying to instantiate a new object from the singleton.

Try the following (PHP 7):

```
class Single
{
    private function __construct() {}
}

class SingleTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    function testCannotCallConstructor()
    {
        try {
            $single = new Single();
            $this->fail('Should never be called!');
        } catch (\Throwable $e) {
            $this->assertNotEmpty($e->getMessage());
        }

        //alternative:
        $this->expectException(\Error::class);
        $single = new Single();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By design, unit test usually checks a behavior, not an interface (method signature is a part of the interface).

But if you really need that you can use the Reflection API. Check the class [`hasMethod()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/reflectionclass.hasmethod.php) and this method [`isPrivate()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/reflectionmethod.isprivate.php).

In the PHP7 enviroment you can use `try/catch` solution proposed by John Joseph, but i recommend to intercept only [`Error`](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.error.php) exceptions (`Throwable` covers all possible erros, not only visibility violation). Also PHPUnit has a [`@expectedException`](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.expectedException) annotation, it's better than manual `try/catch`.

Answer (score 0):

All of these are working perfectly.

```
function testCannotCallConstructor()
{
    try {
        $log = new Log();
        $this->fail('Should never be called!');
    } catch (\Throwable $e) {
        $this->assertNotEmpty($e->getMessage());
    }

    //alternative:
    $this->expectException(\Error::class);
    $log = new Log();
}



public function testConstructPrivate(){
    $method = new \ReflectionMethod('\\Core\\Log', '__construct');
    $result = $method->isPrivate();
    $this->assertTrue( $result, "Log __construct is not private. Singleton not guaranteed.");
}
```

Thank you very much. I think the one I prefer is the **expectException** method.